# Error querying filter in Hebrew

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *getDatosSelect=nil;
NSMutableString *consulta=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[consulta appendString:@"SELECT idOzDiccionario, espanyol, ingles, hebreo, fonetica FROM ozdiccionario WHERE UPPER(ingles) LIKE 'FRIEND%'"];
if ( sqlite3_prepare_v2(sql,[consulta UTF8String],[consulta length],&resultado,&siguiente) == SQLITE_OK ){
    getDatosSelect=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        while (sqlite3_step(resultado)==SQLITE_ROW){
            NSMutableArray *datos=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int x=0; x<sqlite3_column_count(resultado); x++) {
            char *pChar=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(resultado, x);
            if (pChar!=nil) {
                [datos addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String: pChar]];
            }
        }
        [getDatosSelect addObject:datos];
        datos=nil;
    }
}else {
    NSString *errores=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(sql)];
        NSLog(@"%@ %@",TAG,errores);
}
```

which runs correctly while if I run this other code

```
NSMutableArray *getDatosSelect=nil;
NSMutableString *consulta=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[consulta appendString:@"SELECT idOzDiccionario, espanyol, ingles, hebreo, fonetica FROM ozdiccionario WHERE hebreo='חבר'"];
if ( sqlite3_prepare_v2(sql,[consulta UTF8String],[consulta length],&resultado,&siguiente) == SQLITE_OK ){
    getDatosSelect=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    while (sqlite3_step(resultado)==SQLITE_ROW){
        NSMutableArray *datos=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int x=0; x<sqlite3_column_count(resultado); x++) {
            char *pChar=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(resultado, x);
            if (pChar!=nil) {
                [datos addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String: pChar]];
            }
        }
        [getDatosSelect addObject:datos];
        datos=nil;
    }
}else {
    NSString *errores=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(sql)];
        NSLog(@"%@ %@",TAG,errores);
}
```

I get the following error:

> unrecognized token: ""◊ó◊ë◊"

This error occurs when the method converts a string to UTF8 character

Why? What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You've used `[consulta length]` as the number of bytes in `consulta`. That is not correct. `length` is the number of characters. The number of bytes could be more, and Hebrew generally will be. To get the length, you need to use:

```
[consulta lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It is likely that your queries are being truncated, so they may or may not work depending on their exact content.